# Есть задача сверстать сайт для слабовидящих и слепых людей где можно найти полезную информацию?

Tags: html, css

Все что я нашел в интернете это какое то общее описание. А нужно конкретно, блоки должны верстается так, последовательность такая, навигация такая и т.д. Использовать такие то и такие тэги

---

чтение будет происходит с экранного диктора

Comment: `А нужно конкретно, блоки должны верстается так, последовательность такая, навигация такая и т.д.` - Ну так почему вы этого не сделали?

Comment: @ΝNL993 ТС думает, что сайт для слепых или слабовидящих верстается определённым способом, что порядок дивов и последовательность - имеет значение.

Comment: так и есть, думаю что есть какие то особенности верстки

Answer (score 2):

Во первых вы можете воспользоваться встроенным в любой браузер на основе chromium инструментом `lighthouse`. Он подскажет как улучшить вёрстку и оптимизировать ваш сайт, в том числе и и для слабовидящих.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во вторых вы можете воспользоваться [Этой](https://habr.com/ru/post/347478/) статьёй на хабре, там довольно подробно расписано как это сделать.

Также воспользуйтесь [этой](https://webref.ru/course/html-basics/hierarchy) статьёй об иерархии тегов

Answer (score 0):

На Доке недавно презентовали новый большой раздел, связанный как раз с доступностью: https://doka.guide/a11y/